# Open second drawerlayout as a sub drawerlayout over the first

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview

```
Android Studio 2.1.3
```

I have this design I am trying to follow.

On the first drawerlayout I have a setttings options.

[image]

When the user clicks, it will open a second drawerlayout like this below.

[image]

The user can get back to the first by clicking on the arrow `Main Menu`.

Is this possible?

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: This is possible, but not with the standard menu xml file. You have to do a small hack by adding a custom layout to the `NavigationView`.

Comment: Are you just concerned with how to open a second drawer over the first? I mean, are you also asking how to style those particular items, or you just want the double drawer functionality?

Comment: I would like to click the settings in the first menu and the submenu of settings will animate over the first. This was taken from the amazon app that I was trying to duplicate in my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unclear how exactly you wish to implement your drawer UI, so the following solution is rather generic, in that it should work with `NavigationView`s, `RecyclerView`s, or pretty much whatever type of `View`s you'd like.

This solution uses a custom `ViewSwitcher` subclass that acts as a `DrawerLayout`'s left drawer, and holds two child `View`s, one being the main drawer `View`, and the other being the second drawer that opens over it.

The `DoubleDrawerView` class is a relatively simple `ViewSwitcher` that loads its own `Animation`s, and juggles them appropriately to give the effect of a second drawer opening and closing over the first. It tracks its own state so that it can be restored correctly after a device rotation, etc.

```
public class DoubleDrawerView extends ViewSwitcher {
    private static final int NONE = -1;
    private static final int MAIN_VIEW_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int DRAWER_VIEW_INDEX = 1;

    private Animation slideInAnimation, slideOutAnimation, noAnimation;
    private boolean animating = false;

    private Animation.AnimationListener listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
            animating = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {}
    };

    public DoubleDrawerView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DoubleDrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        slideInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in_left);
        slideOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        noAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.none);
        noAnimation.setAnimationListener(listener);
    }

    public void openInnerDrawer() {
        if (getDisplayedChild() != DRAWER_VIEW_INDEX) {
            setChildAndAnimate(DRAWER_VIEW_INDEX, true);
        }
    }

    public void closeInnerDrawer() {
        if (getDisplayedChild() != MAIN_VIEW_INDEX) {
            setChildAndAnimate(MAIN_VIEW_INDEX, true);
        }
    }

    public boolean isInnerDrawerOpen() {
        return getDisplayedChild() == DRAWER_VIEW_INDEX;
    }

    private void setChildAndAnimate(int whichChild, boolean doAnimate) {
        if (doAnimate) {
            setAnimationForChild(whichChild);
        }
        else {
            setAnimationForChild(NONE);
        }
        animating = doAnimate;
        setDisplayedChild(whichChild);
    }

    private void setAnimationForChild(int whichChild) {
        if (whichChild == DRAWER_VIEW_INDEX) {
            setInAnimation(slideInAnimation);
            setOutAnimation(noAnimation);
        }
        else if (whichChild == MAIN_VIEW_INDEX) {
            setInAnimation(noAnimation);
            setOutAnimation(slideOutAnimation);
        }
        else {
            setInAnimation(null);
            setOutAnimation(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (animating) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.whichChild = getDisplayedChild();
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        setChildAndAnimate(ss.whichChild, false);
    }

    private static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        int whichChild;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            whichChild = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeInt(whichChild);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>
            CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {

            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

`DoubleDrawerView` uses the following XML files for its `Animation`s. These should be in your project's `res/anim/` folder.

`slide_in_left.xml`

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

`slide_out_left.xml`

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

`none.xml`

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

This example's layout is a standard `DrawerLayout` with a `DoubleDrawerView` for its drawer, and two simple `NavigationView`s therein. Do note that the main drawer `View` must be listed first inside the `DoubleDrawerView`, with the second, inner drawer `View` after.

`activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.example.doubledrawer.DoubleDrawerView
        android:id="@+id/double_drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/main_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/settings_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_settings" />

    </com.example.doubledrawer.DoubleDrawerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For the sake of a complete cut and paste example, some simple `res/menu/` files for the `NavigationView`s above.

`navigation_main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_screens"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_screen_1"
            android:title="Screen 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_screen_2"
            android:title="Screen 2"/>
    </group>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_open_settings"
        android:title="Open Settings" />

</menu>
```

`navigation_settings.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_close_settings"
        android:title="Back to Main" />

    <group
        android:id="@+id/group_settings">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_setting_1"
            android:title="Setting 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_setting_2"
            android:title="Setting 2" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

In the example `Activity`, we just get references to the `DoubleDrawerView` and `NavigationView`s, and implement an `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to open and close the inner drawer accordingly.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private DoubleDrawerView doubleDrawerView;
    private NavigationView mainNavigationView, settingsNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        doubleDrawerView = (DoubleDrawerView) findViewById(R.id.double_drawer_view);
        mainNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_navigation_view);
        settingsNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.settings_navigation_view);

        mainNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        settingsNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_open_settings:
                doubleDrawerView.openInnerDrawer();
                break;

            case R.id.menu_close_settings:
                doubleDrawerView.closeInnerDrawer();
                break;

                // Additional cases as needed
                // This example simply Toasts the title for the extra sample items

            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses two `DrawerLayout`s, one nested in the other, in lieu of a custom `View`. This might be slightly easier to implement, but it requires a bit more specialized code in the `Activity` itself, and therefore will be more tightly coupled to whichever classes it's used in.

The `Activity`'s layout, `activity_main.xml`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/main_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/settings_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_settings" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The example `NavigationView`s above use the same menu files as shown in [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39050339).

In the `Activity`, we get references to both `DrawerLayout`s, and set the scrim color and lock mode on the inner one at startup. We also need to handle the back button press ourselves, as the addition of a second `DrawerLayout` messes with the first's handling of it. Upon opening and closing the inner drawer, we need to set the lock mode appropriately, to prevent dragging the inner drawer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout, innerDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationView mainNavigationView, settingsNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        innerDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.inner_drawer_layout);
        mainNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_navigation_view);
        settingsNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.settings_navigation_view);

        mainNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        settingsNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        innerDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        innerDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void openInnerDrawer() {
        innerDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        innerDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
    }

    private void closeInnerDrawer() {
        innerDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        innerDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_open_settings:
                openInnerDrawer();
                break;

            case R.id.menu_close_settings:
                closeInnerDrawer();
                break;

            // Additional cases as needed
            // This example simply Toasts the title for the extra sample items

            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```