# How to create NavigationDrawer like PayTm?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to create `NavigationDrawer` like PayTm.

How can I implement double `NavigationDrawer`?

I already search on the Internet but didn't get any clue.

[image]

Comment: Create a view for the second menu and animate it in.

Comment: You'd have to alter the animations, but I have one possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39050339.